# C# Valid Syntax (variable declaration within IF statement without parentheses)

Tags: c#, syntax, compiler-errors

I have a simple question which I can not seem to understand.

Why is this valid c#:

```
if (node != null)
{
     string fullAddress = node.InnerText;
}
```

And this is not?

```
if (node != null)
     string fullAddress = node.InnerText;
```

Is this a bug in the compiler or is this intended?

Comment: What you expect second version to do? `fullAddress` will not be visible outside that single line if it is allowed... (Check C# specification - most likely declaration is not statement)

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I expected it to not have a syntax error!

Comment: I mean what result you suggest this code to produce (ignoring the fact it is invalid C# syntax) - i.e. how that `fullAddress` variable would be visible *after* `if` statement in case of false condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can’t declare local variable inside conditional statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246898/cant-declare-local-variable-inside-conditional-statement)

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823427/why-this-compile-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable declarations following if statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496589/variable-declarations-following-if-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior and makes sense if you remember that `if` takes one statement - so scope of variable declaration would end immediate after it is declared if such syntax is allowed.

Details covered in C# 5.0 specification sections 8.5 (thanks Rob Harvey for link) and  grammar in section B.2.5:

Section 8.5:

> A declaration-statement declares a local variable or constant. Declaration statements are permitted in blocks, but are not permitted as embedded statements.

Grammar from section B.2.5:

```
statement:
  labeled-statement
  declaration-statement
  embedded-statement

embedded-statement:
  block 
  ...

if-statement:
   if   (   boolean-expression   )   embedded-statement
```

As you can see variable declaration (`declaration-statement`) is not `embedded-statement` and hence can't be used in `if-statement`.

Note of C# specification location:

- older version can be found online on MSDN (i.e. above mentioned [Section 8.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664741%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from Anirudh answer)
- latest comes with VS installation and usually located in "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx" folder. See also [Where can I find the C# 5 language specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467103/where-can-i-find-the-c-sharp-5-language-specification)

Answer (score 7):

Because you're defining a local variable without an enclosing scope.

Comment: +1 That's a lot more succinct than how I was going to explain it.

Comment: Thanks.  Wish I knew enough about the C# specification to quote that part of the specification that states this rule, but I suspect that it is implied, rather than stated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is more or less explicit in the specification - I've added excerpt in my answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: It's specifically forbidden in Section 8.5 of the specification.

Answer (score 5):

Well [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664741%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) say this

> Declaration statements are permitted in blocks, but are not permitted
>   as embedded statements.

Answer (score 4):

When you write an `if` without braces, the compiler treats the single statement as if there *were* braces, so:

```
if (node != null)
     string fullAddress = node.InnerText;
```

essentially gets turned into:

```
if (node != null)
{
     string fullAddress = node.InnerText;
}
```

However, note that the scope of `fullAddress` is only within the braces, so the variable can never be used.  The compiler is smart enough to know this, and so it flags it as an error because it knows that no sane programmer would ever do this.  :)

I think this is actually a common theme in the .NET compilers - they have a lot of sanity checking to make sure you don't do something that doesn't make sense, and will often optimize their output  based on various code patterns.

Comment: Thank you Michael.  I was always just thrown off why it produces a syntax error, but "no sane programmer would ever do this" and the compiler knows it is actually the correct answer.  I never actually thought about how useless the "invalid" syntax was.  I upvote your answer because it helped me understand, but Alexei got the bonus points for Grammar from section B.2.5!

Comment: +1. This is the only answer that actually explains the reasoning behind the decision by the compiler team, rather than just stating what the specification says.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (node != null)
  string fullAddress = node.InnerText;
```

This is Visual basic style of code writing where you do not have to use brackets. Also, in C# only one line of statement executes if we do not give the bracket. However, if we need to execute multiple more line of code then we will have to use bracket.